# How to anchor angled text animation to bottom right of screen without bleeding into footer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

As you can see, there are a couple of issues:

1. I want the angled text to stay fixed at the bottom right portion of the screen. When I resize the screen, the angled text moves as well, sometimes completely going offscreen
2. The angled text is bleeding into the footer. Is there a way to cut off the text once it reaches the footer, with a 5px padding? As in, any words that are scrolling, if they reach 5px above the footer, they should disappear. I tried this with the .background-text padding but it doesn't seem to take effect. It's fine if the text runs off the screen on the righthand side, but bleeding into the footer is the issue.
3. The text is currently floating in the middle of the screen. I tried to manipulate the transform and transform-origin properties to hook it to the bottom right, but in my fiddle screen it shows up in the middle of the screen. How can I correct this?
4. Even though I set the animation to be an infinite loop, it glitches for a split second every time the loop restarts

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=League+Spartan');
body {
  font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

.header {
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.menu-item {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.right-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.bottom-right {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.background-text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(10%, 10%) rotate(-35deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.text1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Prevent text from wrapping */
  color: #E8E5E5;
  animation: scrollRight 20s linear infinite;
}

.text2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #E8E5E5;
  animation: scrollLeft 20s linear infinite;
}

.text3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #E8E5E5;
  animation: scrollRight 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  /* Start position */
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-5%);
  }
  /* End position */
}

@keyframes scrollLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-5%);
  }
  /* Start position */
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  /* End position */
}

.footer-line {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: -10px;
}

.footer-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">Homepage</div>
    <div class="menu-item">About</div>
    <div class="menu-item">FAQ</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-content">
      <div class="header">
        <div> Welcome to my site! Here you can learn about different cars</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-content">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom-right">
    <div class="background-text">
      <div class="text1">Proche • Honda • Hyundai • Toyota • Camry •</div>
      <div class="text2">Acura • Lamborghini • Ferrari • Ford • BMW • Audi • </div>
      <div class="text3">Cadillac • Fiat • Kia • Mazda • Maserati •
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <hr class="footer-line" />
  <p class="footer-text">&copy; Copyright 2024 cario. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: What angled text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following styles - added some background-colors to make the effect more visible:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background-text {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: blue; // you can remove this
  z-index: 10;
}

.footer-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: red; // change this to white
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Pay attention to `footer` - this selects the Element . In your code you have `.footer`, with a `.` - this selected a class footer `class="footer"`

To make an element be fixed, you have to set only the anchor values. In your case, if you want it at bottom right, then you do:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 16px; // change margin as needed
```

It's a good habit to set these values as 0 to make the anchor effect and then add margins as needed.

To make your fixed element appear "behind" another element, there are two things you have to add.

First is a background on the element that'll appear "above", otherwise, even if it's above another element, it'll be transparent and will not have the desired effect.

Second, you have to give both elements a position value - fixed, absolute, or relative - and then add a z-index to both elements.
The one with a higher z-index will appear on top of the other.
It's also a good habit to use positive z-indexes, in this case, I used 10 for the fixed element and 20 for the footer, making it so that the footer is on top of the fixed element - note that the footer has a background and position: relative.

Comment: Please put your solution in a demo using the editor.